# Actions and QueryString parameters in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, query-string, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want to have my generic route determine if a query string was passed in the Url like this

```
http://localhost/query/DailyLogs/1?dateOfLog='1/13/2013'
```

Here is my current Route definition:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "query/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
```

---

I have read some answers that say to add the dateOfLog value as an optional action on the Route defintion:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "query/{controller}/{id}/{dateOfLog}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
            dateOfLog = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This does not seem to work, maybe I am doing something wrong, I am not sure.

---

This is how I am currently handling the problem, but I would like to use the ModelBinding power of the Routing Engine:

```
 var queryValue = Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
 string dateOfLog = queryValue["dateOfLog"];
```

Please tell me how to create a Route definition that will use ModelBinding correctly and map my custom url to the controller's parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the controller action, just include `DateTime dateOfLog` as a method parameter and continue to use the query string as it will get mapped just fine, Web API will use the correct method overload if it finds it.

Comment: I have tried that, with no success. Here is the method signature: public DailyLogResponse Get(int id, DateTime dateOfLog), using the route above this never hits the method.

Comment: Ok, try using a string type rather than DateTime in the method parameter.

Comment: Yes, you are correct it is actually a DateTime parsing error, when I changed the parameter type to string the method fires and the values are present. Thanks.

Comment: That is probably b/c your query-string parameter includes single-quotes, which is unnecessary in a URL. Also, your forward slash date-part separates should be URL encoded